# How to use bash aliases in mySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, alias

I don't really care for bash aliases really, but is it possible to get shortcuts for mysql functions? Say if i wanted to describe a table is it possible for me to just do `ds table_name` instead of typing the whole thing out?

I am using the following if it matters:
bash --version `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
mysql --version `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`

Comment: How about using a GUI interface, so you can point and click?

Comment: my cat ate the mouse today. i dont really have a pointer at the mo.

Comment: I think the mysql CLI uses the readline library, in which case you could define a keyboard macro. But it has nothing to do with bash.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases can be defined on the command line, in .bash_profile, or in .bash  with the syntax like

```
$ alias name='unix command with options'
```

Please have a look [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-bash-alias-examples/) for a detailed info..:)

Comment: yeah but those dont really work in mysql cli do they?

Comment: it will..see the link i have given ..:)

Comment: I have! and i have previously defined the following alias in .bash_aliases `alias ds='describe'` and mySQL throws an error if i try to use it in cli. which makes sense, because bash aliases should't be read by mysql? but i tried anyway. thnx for trying.

Comment: Did it helped you ??..:)if yes kindly upvote it as an answer ..or ask if its not fixed

Comment: not fixed. even though i made the bash_alias, i cant use it in mysql

Comment: have a look http://superuser.com/questions/812511/alias-mysql-in-bashrc-not-working-after-login-reboot

Comment: well that question is also about running bash alias in bash. which is running okay for me. if i do `ds` in bash i get `describe: command not found` which is the expected result. the thing im trying to do is run `ds` inside mysql cli, and it should expand to describe which is not working.